# How to run a .dll test suite with CMake and Microsoft Unit Test Framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, clr, cil

In a CMake project, I generated a C++/CLI project and a testing SHARED library according to this post

[CMake for integrated Microsoft Unit Testing Framework (VS2017)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53709197/cmake-for-integrated-microsoft-unit-testing-framework-vs2017)

I am trying to run the tests, but neither `Visual Studio` or `Visual Studio Code` are able to discover my tests.

The unique difference is that I am created a `test` subfolder as a CMake subproject, with it's respective CMakeLists.txt, but is exactly the same config.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

### Analysis of the linked question

The answer to the question you linked has several problems:

- It uses some very old school CMake techniques ([include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) + [link_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html)). Please use some more recent 3.x version of CMake and apply modern CMake techniques [[1]](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake) [[2]](https://gist.github.com/mbinna/c61dbb39bca0e4fb7d1f73b0d66a4fd1).
- Also, you should not pass the `SHARED`/`STATIC` keyword to [add_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) and rather use the [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) variable to control whether to build shared or static binaries.
- It is incomplete. You need to call [add_test()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html) to create a test for [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ctest.1.html), otherwise neither ctest nor an IDE can be aware of your unit tests. Also [enable_testing()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) needs to be called in the top-level project, otherwise `add_test()` has no effect.

### Minimal working example

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(so70759660)
list(PREPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

if(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL AND BUILD_TESTING)
  enable_testing()
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

`tests/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(MSUnitTestFramework REQUIRED)
find_program(VSTest_EXECUTABLE NAMES vstest.console.exe REQUIRED)

add_library(mytest)
target_sources(mytest PRIVATE Mytest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest PRIVATE MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework)
add_test(NAME mytest COMMAND "${VSTest_EXECUTABLE}" "$<TARGET_FILE:mytest>")
```

`cmake/FindMSUnitTestFramework.cmake`:

```
add_library(MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MSUnitTestFramework::MSUnitTestFramework PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "$ENV{VCInstallDir}Auxiliary/VS/UnitTest/include"
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "$ENV{VCInstallDir}Auxiliary/VS/UnitTest/lib/x86/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.lib"
)
set(MSUnitTestFramework_FOUND TRUE)
```

> Notes:
>
> - Using an `IMPORTED` target and linking it via [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) is the modern alternative to `include_directories()`/`include_libraries()`.
> - The `FindMSUnitTestFramework` module is responsible for locating and creating this imported target. Please note that the example that I provided is rather hard-coded and not very "smart" at finding the library and maybe considering things like different Visual Studio versions or target architectures. You may need to improve this.

`tests/MyTest.cpp`:

```
#include <CppUnitTest.h>
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

TEST_CLASS(Class1) {
  public:
    TEST_METHOD(Method1) { Assert::AreEqual(0, 0); }
    TEST_METHOD(Method2) { Assert::AreNotEqual(0, 42); }
};
```

`CMakePresets.json`:

```json
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "vs2022",
            "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl",
                "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl",
                "BUILD_TESTING": "ON",
                "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "ON"
            }
        }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "vs2022",
            "configurePreset": "vs2022"
        }
    ],
    "testPresets": [
        {
            "name": "vs2022",
            "configurePreset": "vs2022",
            "configuration": "Debug"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Compatibility

I was only able to get this running by using a Visual Studio generator in combination with a MSVC toolchain. For other generators (Ninja, Make, etc.) I always got a linker error, but could not figure out what the cause is.

VS Code does display the test in the test explorer (you probably require the [CMake Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fredericbonnet.cmake-test-adapter) extension), but Visual Studio does not. I suspect this is a general problem, that VS only recognizes the `add_test(<name> <command> <args>)` signature but not `add_test(NAME <name> COMMAND <command> ...)` with multi-config generators. Here is a related [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/1643130). But unfortunately, the first signature won't suffice, because it does not support generator expressions like `$<TARGET_FILE:...>`.

### Personal opinion

IMHO if you have a choice which unit testing framework/library to use, I would recommend you agains using *Microsoft Unit Test Framework* for several reasons:

- You restrict yourself to a MSVC toolchain.
- It is rather tailors towards Visual Studio/MSBuild. Itegrating it into any other build system is rather tedious.
- AFAIK you can't even install it separately, but only install it as part of Visual Studio.
- It is not cross-platform, so you will always be stuck with Windows.

My recommendation would be to use something cross-platform that can be used with different compilers/toolchains, is possibly open-source and provides some better integration with other build systems. Examples include GTest, Catch, Boost.Test, etc. With those, you could use a single-config generator like e.g. Ninja and then the test explorer in Visual Studio should discover them.*emphasized text*

Comment: Hey peter_w thanks for your time and your nice answer. 
I've encountered two problems:
- 1º: ·$ENV{VCInstallDir} does not work. I've had to write the path manually
- 2º: Tests run only as a static library. As shared the FWK it's telling me that it can't discover any tests on the `.dll`. Also, as Static, no logs appears, no test runned. Only a green confirmation, but no test runned

Comment: Definitly not working. I just go ahead and copy-pasted your full working example. Tests just run but always passes. I changed the values in order to make them fail, but still passes.
Note that I am using VS2022 (VsCode also).

Comment: Regarding your first problem, for a portable Find module it might be worth having a look at [vswhere](https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki). Regarding your second problem, I can confirm, that the tests always pass when built as a static library, though I don't know why :/ However, when built as shared library, everything works as expected for me, at least in VS Code. I've added my `CMakePresets.json` to the answer, maybe that helps you.

Comment: Very good information, looks to be the only available article found on the internet.
BTW, `CMakeLists.txt` doesn't have to be on the top-level project, I have it on sub-folder and works properly. May be the latest version of Visual Studio CMake Tool is adapted for this. 
I've also included `tests/CMakeLists.txt` code in the main `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @peter_w Any idea why Test Cases are not displayed in Test Explorer on Visual Studio?